# SimpleDateFormat returns string date in different languages

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

Im using SimpleDateFormat to parse the correct date.

Sometimes when i use SimpleDateFormat it returns the me the date in other language than english.

I want the date string to be only in english. Is the possible?

See my code and pictures.

Here is my formater:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Here is same app but string is in different languages:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for helping

Comment: Does this happen when you run your code on different machines? I'm assuming you don't just see erratic language behaviour on the same machine with no changes to the environment...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to change

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Why will this fix the problem?

Comment: Presumably because there is a UK English and a US English

Comment: Not all devices have Locale.ENGLISH installed. But Locale.US is guaranteed to be available.

Answer (score 7):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy", new Locale("ar")); //for example arabic laguage
```

you ca check [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/locale-140624.html) for more details.

Comment: here is the complete list of the country language code: https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Answer (score -3):

just try this----> `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy");`