# how to convert language of Simple Date Format

Tags: java

I am a newbie to programming, my teacher has assigned me a homework, which one part of it is to show the date that entered. I used SimpleDateFormat "dd/MMMM/yyyy". But when is running, It shows the month in the language of my country.

For exam, if I enter 10-02-2001, is will show up 10-tháng 2( february in my country)-2001. I want change it to English. Please help me. (Sorry for my bad English)

The code:

```
public Date getDate(String msg, String err, String format){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        Date date = null;
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        while(true){
            try {
                System.out.print(msg);
                String value = input.readLine();
                date = sdf.parse(value);
                Date now = new Date();
                if(date.after(now)){
                    System.out.println("Your input date is bigger than present");
                    continue;
                }
                break;
                
            } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
                System.out.println(err);
            }
        }
        return date;
    }
```

---

```
Date dateInput = validate.getDate("Enter Date: ", "Date invalid", "dd/MM/yyyy");
        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        String date = sdf.format(dateInput);
        
        double amount = validate.getDouble("Enter Amount: ", "Please enter a real number", 0, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: I think you can utilize a `Locale` for this instead of implicitly using the one of your system. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string/1661389). But please consider using a modern api for date and time, that's `java.time`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat returns string date in different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17421660/simpledateformat-returns-string-date-in-different-languages)

Comment: You can use java localization features, in addtion you should consider to learn to use the new Java DateTime API introduced in java8, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661325/simpledateformat-and-locale-based-format-string

Comment: use locale with Simgple Date format. E.g: SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the locale as well, like so:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If you do not specify the locale it will use the default locale. See [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass locale to SimpleDateFormat costructor. Try this:

```
        Date now = new Date();
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat​("dd/MMMM/yyyy", Locale.CHINA).format(now));    
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat​("dd/MMMM/yyyy", Locale.US).format(now));
```

And as of java 8 you can do somthing like that:

```
    System.out.println(Instant.now()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
```